# How to randomize the questions asked in this python quiz

Tags: python, random

This is some recent code that I have created that runs a multiple choice quiz for states and their capitals in python. As of now, it runs to show the questions asked in order of the "state" and "answer" based on "Increment". I am looking to randomize these questions asked so the order changes every time but every question is only asked once.

```
def Instruction():
    name = input("What is your name? ")
    return name

def askQuestion(num):
    Increment = 0
    NumCorrect = 0
    States = ["RI", "CT", "SC", "AZ", "AL", "AK", "AR", "HI", "MA", "OH"]
    Choices = [["Newport", "Bristol", "Providence", "Cranston"],
               ["Hartford", "New Haven", "Bridgeport", "New London"],
               ["Ashton", "Columbia", "Bowling Green", "Charleston"],
               ["Mesa", "Tucson", "Phoenix", "Scottsdale"],
               ["Auburn", "Huntsville", "Birmingham", "Montgomery"],
               ["Anchorage", "Juneau", "Fairbanks", "Nome"],
               ["Hot Springs", "Fayettevile", "Little Rock", "Bentonville"],
               ["Honolulu", "Kailua", "Hilo", "Waimea"],
               ["Worchester", "Newburyport", "Lynn", "Boston"],
               ["Cincinnati", "Cleveland", "Columbus", "Akron"]]
    Answer = [2,0, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 0, 3, 2]
    while Increment < num:
        print("What is the capital of", States[Increment] + "?")#prints out either what is the capital of RI or CT
        for i in range(len(Choices[Increment])):
            print(str(i)+" " + str(Choices[Increment][i]))
        UserIn = int(input("input your choice "))
        if UserIn == Answer[Increment]:
            print("Correct!") 
            NumCorrect += 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect")
        

        Increment = Increment + 1
    return NumCorrect



NUMQuestions = 10
print("This is a capitals quiz, consisting of", NUMQuestions ,"questions, you will have one chance per question.")
name=Instruction()
print("Hello", str(name))
print("How well do you know the capitals of the states?")
print("Lets find out")



numCorrect = askQuestion(NUMQuestions)    

print(name, ",", "you got",numCorrect,"correct.", "That is equal to",((numCorrect/NUMQuestions)*100),"%")

final = (numCorrect/NUMQuestions)*100

grade = final
if grade >= 90 :
    letterGrade = "A"
elif grade >= 80 :
    letterGrade = "B"
elif grade >= 70 :
    letterGrade = "C"
elif grade >= 60 :
    letterGrade = "D"
else :
    letterGrade = "F"
print("Your letter grade is:", letterGrade)
```

Answer (score 2):

This will be a lot easier if you make a list that groups the state, guesses, and correct answer together in one list. Then you can just use `random` to `shuffle()` it. For example:

```
import random

def askQuestion(num):    
    questions = [
        ('RI', ['Newport', 'Bristol', 'Providence', 'Cranston'], 2),
        ('CT', ['Hartford', 'New Haven', 'Bridgeport', 'New London'], 0),
        ('SC', ['Ashton', 'Columbia', 'Bowling Green', 'Charleston'], 1),
        ('AZ', ['Mesa', 'Tucson', 'Phoenix', 'Scottsdale'], 2),
        ('AL', ['Auburn', 'Huntsville', 'Birmingham', 'Montgomery'], 3),
        ('AK', ['Anchorage', 'Juneau', 'Fairbanks', 'Nome'], 1),
        ('AR', ['Hot Springs', 'Fayettevile', 'Little Rock', 'Bentonville'], 2),
        ('HI', ['Honolulu', 'Kailua', 'Hilo', 'Waimea'], 0),
        ('MA', ['Worchester', 'Newburyport', 'Lynn', 'Boston'], 3),
        ('OH', ['Cincinnati', 'Cleveland', 'Columbus', 'Akron'], 2)
    ]

    random.shuffle(questions)
    num_correct = 0

    for state, guesses, correct in questions[0:num]:
        print(f"What is the capital of {state}?")
        print(*[f'{i} {g}' for i, g in enumerate(guesses)], sep='\n')
        
        guess = int(input("input your choice "))
        
        if guess == correct:
            print("Correct!") 
            num_correct += 1
        else:
            print("Incorrect")
    
    return num_correct

askQuestion(3)
```